# Is Habitat Implementation using ReactJs, for all (3) Sitecore Headless Modes available?

Tags: habitat, jss

Is there any reference implementation available from Sitecore or 3rd Party for Sitecore Headless Mode (API Mode, Integrated Mode, SSR Mode) & React Js.

I am expecting a sample project like [Habitat](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat), where there is a complete implementation using ReactJs (for all 3 modes). Please share the details & reference links.

Answer (score 2):

The official Habitat Home JSS example application from Sitecore is available on the Sitecore Omni GitHub: https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.HabitatHome.Omni

This example uses React, but my understanding is that it only has a single mode in the example. It is a complete implementation of a fictional "Habitat Fitness" brand that shows Sitecore functionality like personalization in a JSS application.